# MongoDB - Pushing or Updating an element in Array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

In products collection, i have an Array of `recentviews` which has 2 fields `viewedBy` & `viewedDate`.

I am on to `$push` a fresh element in Array, so i am using below query :-

```
db.produts.update( { _id: 'ObjectId("536c55bf9c8fb24c21000095")' },
                    { $push: { recentviews: [ { viewedby: 'xyz', vieweddate: ISODate("2014-05-09T04:12:47.907Z") } ] } }
            )
```

What is wrong in the above query?

Further If the record already exists for e.g if there is already a record with `viewedby` : `xyz`, i need to update the record i.e `vieweddate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the brackets `[]`:

```js
db.produts.update( 
    { _id: ObjectId("536c55bf9c8fb24c21000095") },
    { 
        "$push": { 
            "recentviews": { 
                "viewedby": "xyz",
                "vieweddate": ISODate("2014-05-09T04:12:47.907Z")
            } 
        }
    }
)
```

So when adding a new sub-document to an array it is just specified that way and added to the array that is mentioned on the left side.

Also your `ObjectId` value was quoted which would have stopped the `.update()` from matching.

Comment: Works good...thanks....What query should i use for my further issue, if record already exists, i need to `update` it rather than `pushing` it? Any suggestions..!

Comment: @Anup If you have another question then feel free to post another question. It is the best way to explain what you are trying to do and it might just even earn you some reputation should others find it useful to them

Comment: @Anup Don't forget to accept your answers. It let's others know your issue is solved.

Comment: Indeed i do forgotten this time.. :)

Answer (score 1):

`{ _id: 'ObjectId("536c55bf9c8fb24c21000095")' }` should be without quotes as with quotes it is treated as string instead of objectId, which is not equal to your primary key.

`{ _id: ObjectId("536c55bf9c8fb24c21000095") }`

```
x1:PRIMARY> typeof( 'ObjectId("536c55bf9c8fb24c21000095")' )
string
x1:PRIMARY> typeof( ObjectId("536c55bf9c8fb24c21000095") )
object
```